# Why is interrogating done with roll+CHA instead of +STR?

Tags: dungeon-world

The *Dungeon World* manual pretty clearly states that forceful interrogation (using the threat of violence as *leverage*) is a *Parley* move. However, parley is played roll+CHA which feels a bit strange when you're not talking about negotiating but basically about [the threat of] torture. Wouldn't a roll+STR check make more sense?

Is that something you would solve with a different, or custom move, or does CHA make sense in a way that I don't see?

Comment: Why would strength be relevant even to torture? It doesn't take much strength at all to slide a knife under a fingernail.

Comment: Perhaps you can choose whichever answer you found most helpful as "best answer"

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**"To parley, you have to have leverage."**

For the *Parley* move to trigger you have to have something over the NPC or something the NPC wants. Dungeon World uses the term leverage to describe this:

> "Leverage is anything that could lure the target of your parley to do something for you. Maybe it's something they want or something they don't want you to do. Like a sack of gold. Or punching them in the face."

Thus the threat of violence only establishes the ability for the parley move at all. You still need to convince the target that its in their best interests to work with you, that you won't simply kill them when you are done or that you really will pay them what you promised etc.

**This already exists as an advanced move for the Fighter**

Available from level 2-5 when the player levels up.

> - **Interrogator**
>
>   When you parley using threats of impending violence as leverage, you may use STR instead of CHA.

As such I would suggest leaving it where it is as a fighter advanced move, vs. having this open to other classes.

Comment: Can you add elaboration on why it is normally CHA, since that is also part of the question? (Force of Personality and such.)

Comment: @MrLemon A decent point, though really its a RTM issue because the parley move in the Dungeon World book clearly explains it.

Comment: Suggested edit: It's Charisma because convincing people to do things requires understanding them (even when you're convincing with threat of force), and the essence of being charismatic and charming is understanding people.

Comment: Thanks! Also nice to know about that Fighter move; I hadn't studied the advanced class moves yet for our first session. I think our Fighter will almost certainly use that move :-)

Answer (score 12):

Why CHA and not STR? Because CHA is the stat you use to manipulate people.

There are a lot of reasons why sheer brute strength might not work for interrogation:

- The subject might not believe you'll actually follow through with your threats.
- The subject might not believe you'll *stop* hurting him if you accede to him.
- The subject might not believe that being honest with you will help.
- The subject might not realize how badly getting beaten up will actually hurt.
- And so on...

How do you deal with these problems? By reading the subject, and using a calculated combination of showmanship and patter to work them around to your point of view. That's charisma.

Think of all the interrogations and intimidations you've seen in fiction. There are a few where the big sack of muscles just shows up and things go their way. But *most* of them involve someone talking.

**So what good are muscles to interrogation?**

- Having someone who is obviously physically powerful can give you *leverage.* You need leverage to parley. If you don't have someone that the target is afraid of, you can't use threats of violence as leverage. Simple enough.
- If the narrative dictates that the subject would definitely surrender to someone who was physically powerful, then you shouldn't have to roll parley at all. You ask, and they accede. Sometimes things work out for you.

Comment: "There are a few where the big sack of muscles just shows up and things go their way", and Fighters have an advanced move that lets them do exactly that.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Sure. Also, sometimes the sack of muscles succeeds at a Charisma check.

Comment: Indeed! I'm agreeing entirely, if that was ambiguous. :) (And when the sack of muscles tries with a low CHA anyway and misses, the failure is always interesting, and worth XP!)

Comment: "Is it hot in here, or is it just battleaxe? Anyway, where is the bandit hideout?"

Comment: The interrogated PC in question was actually a dying bandit. Does something like that trigger a *Parley* move?

Comment: That depends, do you consider it leverage? For example, if the bandit is dying, does he believe that if he assists the PCs they will be able to save his life? Or, if you plan to go the torture route, does he believe they can make his death more painful? If he is convinced he is going to die anyway, he might not actually respond to torture well unless the PCs can convince him (CHA) that they would be able to keep him alive for longer and make his death extremely slow and painful.

Comment: @WouterLievens The first question is: Will the bandit tell them what they want to know if they just ask? If the answer to that is "yes" (because he's having second thoughts about his life, or wants to screw over his employer or whatever), then *no roll is required.* If he won't just tell them, then they need leverage and Parley.

Answer (score 2):

Have you ever seen someone in real life, whom you would've estimated to have a really low CHA stat? I have two examples ready:

- The quiet guy: A friend of mine never talks more than two consecutive words, when in a group. In fact he mostly communicates with nods, shrugs and grunts, especially if you try to "force" an answer from him. He is stronger than me, but I'm quite sure, he can't threaten anyone as he won't go out of his usual self.
- The flippy girl: The girlfriend of a friend played an elven whatever (she comes close to the elven barbarian from "Standard Action" webseries). But every time she tries to get violent, she is so excited about it, that she is unable to form whole sentences. In real life she's a karateka and could probably beat me anytime. However if she'd try to interrogate me the hard way, I couldn't comprehend any questions let alone answer them, even if i wanted to.

Charisma isn't just good looks. It's about your effectiveness in social interaction. Looking good may help with the opposite sex, but if you're unable to speak complete sentences for whatever reason it will only get you into bed without achieving what you wanted (if that was something but bed).

Btw. for threatening someone you can also resort to external resources: If you have a high charisma but low strength just go: "He will punch you." instead of "I". In fact that also allows for the good cop, bad cop setup. "Look everything that's holding him from punching you is me. And look at me I can not hold him by force. So give me something that will satisfy him." Suddenly if you play your part convincingly, you're his friend and he can associate to you as you are both opposing the threat from the same **weak** position.

Comment: In Dungeon World, is CHA also your presence of character? There are those people who walk into a room and you can tell they own the place - or they're just an intimidating presence. That would be a contributor!

Comment: I'd say "presence of character" is one good fit, but not the only one. As in strength you might find substitudes: If you are not bulky, you can still apply the strength you have in a more clever way (think about physical term "lever(age)" and ergonomics). Again RL example: A bulky drunk guy tried to lift me at a party just for fun, I saw it coming and held him at arms length. I obviously succeeded the comparative STR check as he was unable to lift me. He never recognized that he was toppling forward, as he had quite some but not enough counter-weight.